# Как научить Telegram бота писать другим людям?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот должен получать контакт человека в первом сообщении, потом текст или файл во втором сообщении и отправлять его контакту из первого сообщения.

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
def read_contact(message):
    adress = message.chat.id
    adress2 = message.contact.user_id
    status = True

    bot.send_message(adress, message.contact.first_name) #Выводит имя контакта


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def letter(message):
    bot.send_message(adress, adress2)
    if status is True:
        bot.send_message(adress2, message.text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(adress2, 'Need contact')



global adress2
global status
bot.polling()
```

В код не стал добавлять импортированные библиотеки и подключение бота.

Бот прекращает работу при отправке сообщения, при приеме контакта id получателя определяется правильно. Есть подозрения что ошибка в передаче адреса в глобальные переменные, но как сделать правильно не знаю...

Comment: Оба пользователя уже общались с ботом? Я это веду к тому, что если пользователь никогда не обращался к боту, то бот такому пользователю не может отправлять сообщение.

Comment: тоесть, телеграм бот в принципе не способен отправлять сообщения первым? даже если дать ему такую команду?

Comment: @Артём Да, из соображений безопасности бот не может первый написать сообщение. Иначе всех нас уже давно заспамили бы, только представьте... Но если пользователь связался первый, то Вы можете запомнить `chat_id` и позже писать ему сколько угодно (пока он не отключит бота). P. S.: упомянуть человека можно с помощью знака `@`, так ему придёт уведомление.

Comment: @nomnoms12, спасибо большое, все понятно